# Windows software loading times

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

Is there a way to find out using programs how much time a Windows program (GUI) like MS Word or Adobe Photoshop took to actually load. I understand loading is a subjective issue. Idea is to find out whether a desktop requires attention or not or whether there is any degradation of performance which a user is facing.

Comment: Define "load".  Do you mean the time for the process to start?  The time to execute the first line of code?  Or the time to see the main window appear on the screen?  Whatever test methodology you choose, make sure you run it multiple times (10x), as there's a lot of variance based on things like if DLLs are already loaded, the system has been recently rebooted, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual Powershell way to time a command or any scriptblock is Measure-Command, for example :

```
Measure-Command { Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" }
```

But this will time only the time Powershell took to spin up the new process, not really the time taken by the application to load a new window and all its interface.

Fortunately, the System.Diagnostics.Process object which is output by Start-Process has a property called Responding.
According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding(v=vs.110).aspx) , this property tells us if the user interface of the associated process is responding to the system.

So we can do this little script :

```
$StartTime = Get-Date
$WordProcess = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" -PassThru
DO
{
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1 
} Until ( $WordProcess.Responding -eq $True )
$EndTime = Get-Date
($EndTime - $StartTime).TotalSeconds
```

The -PassThru allows the command to return a Process object which we store in $WordProcess.
Then , we use the Responding property of this object to check if its user interface is responding.

The DO...Until loop will stop looping as soon as the process is responding.

"Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1" will give us a precision of one millisecond, which should be good enough for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution I think is this one (powershell):

```
$datStartTime = Get-Date
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE" -Wait
$datEndTime = Get-Date
($datEndTime-$datStartTime).TotalSeconds
```

Set the path to the application. Powershell starts the application. Close the application when loaded.
Then you see the time the application needs to open / close.

Comment: The -Wait of Start-Process will wait forever, until the process stops.
This forces you to stop the process (or close the window) to be able to proceed to the last 2 lines.